# stripos vs glob for unlinking

Tags: php, arrays, glob, unlink

I want to delete the files which are not appearing in this array. I know the name of file partially but don't know the size parameter suffixed after file name like `filename-50x75.jpg, filename-100x77.jpg , filename-500x377.jpg`.

I want to delete above images from a directory and don't want to delete below images.

```
$list_of_allowed_images=array("filename-50x50.jpg","filename-50x70.jpg","filename-90x50.jpg","filename-100x100.jpg","filename-150x150.jpg","filename-250x200.jpg","filename-300x250.jpg","filename-360x270.jpg","filename-390x250.jpg","filename-500x345.jpg","filename-768x576.jpg","filename-820x400.jpg","filename-1024x768.jpg");
```

I have the following snippet:

```
foreach(glob($base_path_del.$only_obs_img."[0-9][0-9]*x*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file_to_del_now)
{ 
  if(!in_array($file_to_del_now,$list_of_allowed_images))
  {
    unlink($file_to_del_now);       

   }            
}
```

but I think it can be more efficient. Is another more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You might have better chance on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as you have a working snippet but just want it improved / suggestions for improving.

Comment: @Script47 was not knowing. u guys are so helpful. will make note of this

Comment: However, I think this may potentially be the better approach (compared to `stripos`) as you not only filter the files and get their actual file resource within the one `glob` call, whereas if you used `stripos` you need to still get the file resource.

Comment: @mickmackusa checking ur option. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I recommend:

(untested code)

```
chdir($base_path_del);
$files = glob($only_obs_img."[0-9][0-9]*x*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
$whitelist_regex = "/-(?:50x[57]0|90x50|100x100|150x150|250x200|300x250|360x270|390x250|500x345|768x576|820x400|1024x768)\.jpg$/i";
$removables = preg_grep($whitelist_regex, $files, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
foreach ($removables as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);       
}
```

So...

Change the current working directory so that `glob()` doesn't include the paths in the collection of qualifying files.

Invert `preg_grep()` so that files that don't match the whitelist regex requirements are retained.

Then just loop the naughty list and delete the lot.

The regex pattern boils down your whitelist array logic. The check starts at the last `-` in the filename, checks the dimensions, checks `.jpg` case-insensitively, then ensures that the filename has ended.

p.s. or `array_map()` if you don't want to break the functional style.

```
array_map('unlink', $removables);
```